# Rails ActiveModelSerialzer include with transform_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have ZoneSerializer

```
class Api::V1::ZoneSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :address, :description, :groupname, :key, :speed_limit

  has_many :radius_user_groups
end
```

And I set `transform_key`

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.key_transform = :camel_lower
```

When I get response from server I get `radiusUserGroups` which is ok. But frontend sends also `radiusUserGroups` for includes, but there seems to be no autotransform feature for backend. Should I do this manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in your **Application controller** This method convert all params to snake_case :

```
before_action :deep_snake_case_params!

  def deep_snake_case_params!(val = params)
    case val
    when Array
      val.map {|v| deep_snake_case_params! v }
    when Hash
      val.keys.each do |k, v = val[k]|
        val.delete k
        val[k.underscore] = deep_snake_case_params!(v)
      end
      val
    else
      val
    end
  end
```